# App Store: Make in app purchase item free for 1 day

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have an app that is free but contains a in app purchase item that cost 2 dollar.
Is it possible to make this in app purchase item free for 1 day? If I make it free will the user purchasing the item just get up 0 dollar when he tries to purchase it?

Comment: Apple doesn't support this. You can't set the cost of an IAP to free for any period of time.

Comment: Yes it does. When I go to Manage in app purchase I get this screen. Here I can select free in the price tier and when this should take place. http://tinyurl.com/o4f9ouo

Comment: That's new (to me at least). Last time I messed with my IAPs (which I must admit was over a year ago), free was not an option. Good to know.

Comment: Yes could be that this is a new feature. Im interested to know how this appears for the customer. Will he only get the purchase screen as usual but the price will be 0 dollar?

Comment: Can you try it with a test app in the sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Unfortunately I misunderstood what was asked by Nissefar. Sorry, Nissefar.

Below is a completely unrelated text (the original). I'll probably delete it eventually.

---

I'm only writing this as an answer because I don't have enough reputation to comment.

You could use consumables. Make the user buy time to use the item. This requires a backend server for your app, responsible to manage the bought time.

If you really want to disable the purchasing for one day, you can do it as well. When the user buys it, the server is notified, manages what has to manage, and tells all devices the item was bought. All devices disable the possibility to buy the item. Whenever the app starts you ask the server if the item is available or should be set to be bought.

Study a little about In-App Purchases, and you'll know what's the best solution to your *undetailed* problem. Also, if you don't know how your server can notify all devices, study about push notification.

I know this answer isn't very complex, but your question is very simple. You should have explained better what you want, as well as to all solutions you though and their pros and cons. What have you tried to do already?

**I'm not expecting you to aprove this answer, only to improve you question.** Detail it a little better, and explain what you've tried and the solutions you've considered.

Comment: This sounds like an answer to me and not a message so you have done it right +1

Comment: Not sure why I would use my own backend server for this. The app is already published in the app store. It is free and contains a in app purchase for the full version (2 dollars). I want to make this free for 1 day. So all people buying the full version will get it for free this day. In the app store there is a manage in app purchases link and here you can modify the price tier and set it to free. http://tinyurl.com/o4f9ouo   has anyone done/tried this?

Comment: @Nissefer Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I didn't knew it was possible to have free In-App Purchases. If you try it, please share the result for future reference.